# Remove duplicate items without rounding, C++

Tags: c++, duplicates, comparator

I am trying to remove duplicate items from vector using the following comparator

```
            bool operator() ( const Point * p1, const Point * p2 ) const
            {
                    return ( p1->X() < p2->X() ) || ( ( p1->X() == p2->X() ) && ( p1->Y() < p2-Y() ) );
            }
```

and overloaded opeartor ==

```
bool Point::operator == ( const Point &p ) const
{
    return ( x - p.x ) * ( x - p.x ) + ( y - p.y ) * ( y - p.y ) < DIFF;
}
```

schematic removing:

```
std::sort ( it_begin, it_end, Comp );
Points::iterator i_new_end = std::unique ( it_begin, it_end, Uniq);
items.erase ( i_new_end, this->items.end() );
```

However there is a problem with data. Points sorted according to x coordinate

```
-0.0000000015   -6281103.8487118632   0.0000000000
-0.0000000011   -5993359.5353725236   0.0000000000
-0.0000000010   -5523510.0253371494   0.0000000000
-0.0000000009   -4885831.4582128422   0.0000000000
-0.0000000009   -4099699.3745807474   0.0000000000
-0.0000000008   -3189000.0000000000   0.0000000000
-0.0000000008   -2181404.4741311157   0.0000000000
-0.0000000008   -1107528.0771596823   0.0000000000 //unique
-0.0000000008   -0.0000000005   0.0000000000
-0.0000000007   1107528.0771596811   0.0000000000  //unique
-0.0000000007   2181404.4741311143   0.0000000000
-0.0000000007   3188999.9999999991   0.0000000000
-0.0000000006   4099699.3745807474   0.0000000000
-0.0000000006   4885831.4582128404   0.0000000000
-0.0000000005   5523510.0253371485   0.0000000000
-0.0000000004   5993359.5353725236   0.0000000000
0.0000000000   -6281103.8487118632   0.0000000000
0.0000000004   5993359.5353725236   0.0000000000
0.0000000005   5523510.0253371485   0.0000000000
0.0000000006   4099699.3745807474   0.0000000000
0.0000000006   4885831.4582128404   0.0000000000
0.0000000007   1107528.0771596811   0.0000000000
0.0000000007   2181404.4741311143   0.0000000000
0.0000000007   3188999.9999999991   0.0000000000
0.0000000008   -3189000.0000000000   0.0000000000
0.0000000008   -2181404.4741311157   0.0000000000
0.0000000008   -1107528.0771596823   0.0000000000
0.0000000008   -0.0000000005   0.0000000000
0.0000000009   -4885831.4582128422   0.0000000000
0.0000000009   -4099699.3745807474   0.0000000000
0.0000000010   -5523510.0253371494   0.0000000000
0.0000000011   -5993359.5353725236   0.0000000000
0.0000000015   -6281103.8487118632   0.0000000000
0.0089638987   -6377999.9999999991   0.0000000000
```

Operator == does not bring any effect, near points are not sorted next to each other...

Is there any possibility to remove such duplicit points WITHOUT rounding (for exmple a diffrenet comparator)? I know, that coordinates have to many decimal places...

Comment: Are you using STL containers?  If so, you should define operator<, rather than operator==

Comment: How do you use the operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Operator == does not bring any effect, near points are not sorted next to each other...

If the type of `x` and `y` is float or double, then equality cannot be done reliably.

Consider using `numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()` or `numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` when comparison!

Is `DIFF` in your implementation equal to `numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()`? (where T is the data type: float or double)

Comment: And therefore he does a comparison with what appears to be a constant, `DIFF`

Comment: @Arkadiy: I think he wanted to remove duplicates using `std::unique()`, and that needs `==`.

Comment: Right you are - I did not realize his operator () is used as "<". Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

std::sort needs operator <, not operator ==

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` uses `operator<`.  `std::unique` uses `operator==`.

In STL there is a distinction between *equality*, defined by `operator==`,and *equivalence*, defined using `operator<`:

> Two objects are equivalent if neither
>   precedes the other in some sort order
>   of interest. Often, equivalent values
>   are equal, but not always. For
>   example, the strings “STL” and “stl”
>   are equivalent in a case-insensitive
>   sort, but they are certainly not
>   equal. For details on the distinction
>   between equivalence and equality,
>   consult any good reference on the STL.
>   In Effective STL, the issue is
>   examined in Item 19.

http://drdobbs.com/184401469#1

Answer (score 0):

I think you've encountered an unsolvable problem.  The standard
sort algorithm requires an ordering operator which defines
a strict ordering.  And there's no way to implement it with
"fuzzy" relationships.  You're best bet is to define your
relationship along the same lines as your ==, but without the
epsilon:

```
inline double mag2( Point const& p )
{
    return p.X() * p.X() + p.Y() * p.Y();
}

bool operator()( Point const* lhs, Point const* rhs )
{
    return mag2( *lhs ) < mag2( *rhs );
}
```

(Throwing the epsilon in there anywhere will cause the
relationship order to cease to be strict, and will result in
undefined behavior in the sort algorithm.)